# Need help understanding a discrete math problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I prove that the number of elements in the set $ \mathrm{\{ \varepsilon , a,b,c,....z \}}^n$ is equal to $(\mathrm{26}^{(n+1)}-1)/25$? Where epsilon is the empty string.

What approaches would I take?

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Is $ { ... }^n $ the set of n-length strings?

Comment: I suppose that here the operation is concatenation, so that, *e.g*, the pairs $(a,\varepsilon)$ and $(\varepsilon,a)$ are considered the same string.

Comment: each element in the set is a string, and each string in the set will be concatenated to each other string in the set n number of times. fkraeiem explained it pretty well. it'd be like if you had two words and you just joined them together. in this case, each letter a, b, c, stands for some word.

Comment: Basically, you need to count the strings that consist of $k$ non-$\epsilon$ characters followed by $n-k$ $\epsilon$'s, when $k$ ranges from $0$ to $n$, as any string will reduce to one of those.

Comment: As the set has 27 elements, it's 27$^n$.

Comment: the set has 27 elements only when n is equal to 1, but how do i prove that it is equal to the given formula for higher values of n?

Comment: again, because epsilon is the empty string, concatenating epsilon with any other string in the set doesn't create a new unique string. you are misunderstanding mr wiliam elliot

Answer (score 1):

Since the $\varepsilon$'s disappear, we end up the strings over $\{a,b,\dots,x,y,z\}$ of length at most $n.$  There are $26^k$ strings of length $k$, so we have $$\sum_{k=0}^n26^k = {26^{n+1}-1\over25}$$ different strings.

Note that a single string can arise in many ways, but that doesn't matter.